# How to calculate the sum of odd frequency elements in array using hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, frequency

Gievn following array `arr[] = {5,3,3,3,3,5,5,2}`, I have to produce the sum of only the elements with an odd frequency. My output should be 7, i.e. the sum of 5 + 2.

For some reason, I am getting 10 and I don't understand why.

```
public class OddnumberOfElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2};
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            }
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() % 2 != 0) {
                sum = sum + e.getKey();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `for` loop checks if an int value is already contained as a key within your `map` to increment its frequency. In case the int is already present its corresponding frequency is incremented, but then the opposing condition is **not placed within an else branch**, resetting to 1 the int frequency.

The loop should be written like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
        map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(arr[i], 1);
    }
}
```

Besides, if you're allowed to use streams (I don't know whether this is a school assignment or not), you could achieve what you're doing in a much more compact writing.

```
int arr[] = {5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2};
Integer sum = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting())) //Creating a hashmap where to each int (boxed to Integer) corresponds its frequency
        .entrySet().stream() //Streaming the map's entries
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() % 2 == 1) //for each entry we keep only the ones with an odd frequency
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getKey())); //Summing the values of Integers with an odd frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing else

```
if(map.containsKey(arr[i])){
            map.put(arr[i],map.get(arr[i])+1);
        }
else
        map.put(arr[i], 1);
```

That's why your elements are being initialized with frequency 1 each time instead of incrementing. So output is 5+3+2=10

Answer (score 0):

you are overiding the  increment instead of :

```
 if(map.containsKey(arr[i])){
            map.put(arr[i],map.get(arr[i])+1);
        }
        map.put(arr[i], 1);
```

do

```
 if(map.containsKey(arr[i])){
                map.put(arr[i],map.get(arr[i])+1);
            }
            else map.put(arr[i], 1);
```